# Why is decodeByteArray returning null?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64, android-camera

I am trying to save images to db and retrieve and show them on the UI.

I am using the following code to upload images clicked/from gallery to My SQL.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bitmap photo = null;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);



    }else if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    }

}
```

And the following code to upload it to db.

```
 void createParam(){
     photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayBitmapStream);
     byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
     String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
  }
```

And this code to decode the image string retrieved from db.

```
public Bitmap getImage() {
        if("null".equalsIgnoreCase(image)){
            return null;
        }else{
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,     decodedString.length);
    return decodedByte;
    }
}
```

The problem is decodeByteArray in method is returning null. And the string is not getting decoded. And this issue is not happening for images clicked by front camera.
Please help me in finding the issue!

Comment: 'Base64.DEFAULT);'. does not match 'Base64.NO_WRAP);'.

Comment: greenapps I tried making both of the no_wrap. But that did not help.
I keep on getting this:D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false

Comment: Make both default. For the rest i wonder where your db resides as both is java code. Please tell where you do the encoding and where the decoding.

Comment: I tried making both of them "default" too, But that doesn't work.
There is no issue with DB, as this is working for some clicks, and not for some clicks.

Comment: You did not answer all of my questions.

Comment: I had issue with DB. I was using BLOB type. I changed it to MEDIUMBLOB and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I was getting null as well and got it fixed by setting `options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;`

```
public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}


public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String b64) {
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length, opts);
}
```